# Maximum number of linearly independent quadrics containing a curve in $\mathbb{P}^4$ not contained in a hyperplane?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider everything over $\mathbb{C}$. My question is:

What is the maximal number $k$ of linearly independent homogeneous quadratic forms $Q_1,\dots,Q_k$ in $5$ variables such that the intersection $V(Q_1) \cap \dots \cap V(Q_k) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^4$ has a connected component that is positive dimensional and does not lie on a hyperplane?

I think the answer might be $k=6$; the example I have in mind is that $6$ linearly independent quadrics vanish on the quartic rational normal curve in $\mathbb{P^4}$.

The motivation for my guess comes from the analogous question in $\mathbb{P}^3$; we can ask for the maximal number $k$ of linearly independent homogeneous quadratic forms $Q_1,\dots,Q_k$ in $4$ variables such that the intersection $V(Q_1) \cap \dots \cap V(Q_k) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ has a connected component that is positive dimensional and does not lie in a hyperplane. Here, one can show that the answer is $k=3$, and in fact any such connected component must be a twisted cubic curve.

Crossposted to: [this question on stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322238/maximum-number-of-linearly-independent-quadrics-containing-a-curve-in-mathbbp)

Comment: (Might be worth recording that you appear to have found your answer in MSE link.)